# Libgdx Tiled Map not transparent

Tags: java, libgdx

[image]
I don't know why but my libgdx is not transparent for two layers. You may see in designer and my game. Those grasses are added in different layer. In designer it is transparent while in my game it is showing grey portion over there. Why? :-/

I have added this in create()

```
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("stage.tmx");
OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer maprender = new OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer(map);
```

and this in render()

```
maprender.render();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [set blending](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer.html#setBlending-boolean-) to true:

```
mapenderer.setBlending(true);
```